# Dynamic controls - Moving from WebControls to plain html plus knockout

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js

I have built a 'dynamic' site. Basically, there is a configuration database, where users specify the field type, layout, etc. The controls are then added to screen dynamically based on this configuration. 
I have wrapped the web controls inside my own controls. 
So for example, I have myTextControl, myNumericControl etc.
Then in the code behind, I use a helper that reads the configuration and adds these controls to the screen.
Now, we would like to move from webcontrols to plain html controls + knockout (for a number of reasons such as performance, better ui etc). However, I am a bit confused on this.
For example, should I still use an approach of creating myTextControl, myNumeric etc ... that are plain html controls. For example I could inherit from my own base class and then add the html of these controls to a place holder or literal. should I try to use a viewing engine such as razor?
I know there is MVC but we are not prepared for this step yet.

Any assistance would be greatly apprecaited.

Comment: I've faced a similar issue with knockout.  We've decided to go all in on MVC.  Once we got away from the web controls programming model, the overall effort became simpler.

Comment: photo_tom  - thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, it would not be possible for us to move to MVC. I did not mention that everything is hosted on Sharepoint 2010. And it is very tedious to move to MVC, and the approach is not recommended that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use stripped down asp.net controls:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" ClassName="classname" %>
<div>...your html here...</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, a nice simple solution that may do the trick